# I want to use remaining available space on my page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In the screen, I have a Column, it has a cusotm made widget of specific height. Then, I have Expanded, in which I have a TabBar which has three tabs.

In one of those tabs, I want to show a list. First, I have a padding, which contains column. The column has some text, which should remain at top and the list should be shown in the space which is remaining. I am using Expanded for that, but it is not working.

I can't use ListView directly, and also can't use expanded. It is only working when I am giving it a container of fix size. Now, in different screens, it will look different. So, I want to take all of the remaining space and build the list there. Code for reference -

Here is the doubts screen, which is one of the tabs of main screen -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_board_plus/size_config.dart';
import 'package:my_board_plus/styles.dart';

import '../../api_handling/api_fetch/fetch_doubt_questions.dart';
import '../../data_models/doubt_question_model.dart';

class NewDoubtsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewDoubtsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NewDoubtsScreen> createState() => _NewDoubtsScreenState();
}

class _NewDoubtsScreenState extends State<NewDoubtsScreen> {

  late Future<List<DoubtQuestionModel>> doubtQuestionsList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    doubtQuestionsList = fetchDoubtQuestion();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor2,
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        width: getProportionateScreenWidth(130),
        height: getProportionateScreenHeight(50),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: brandPurple,
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            '?    My Doubts',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 15,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, left: 5),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Trending Doubts',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'View all',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: brandYellow,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Container(
                height: getProportionateScreenHeight(530),
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

The red area that you are seeing is the one. I want it to occupy whole area available in the phone screen, so I can show list in it which should be scrollable. In this case, it is occupying all, but in different screens, it might not. So, please give me some suggestions.

Comment: you can wrap Padding widget with Expanded, because Expanded widget will take the rest of remained space. also no need to give height (getProportionateScreenHeight(530),) to Container.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to give the height of the container like

```
height: double.infinity
```

Or you can give the height of it with substracting the other height from the screen size like

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - getProportionateScreenHeight(50) //the heigth size that you give the other widget that top of it
```

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap your `Padding` widget with the `Expanded` widget,

Expanded widget in column will take the rest of the space of the screen.

also no need to give height to Container widget, so you can remove `getProportionateScreenHeight(530)` this one